# Collision for array of pathfinding zombies to array of blocks

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, python, pygame, collision-avoidance

**Relevant Background Information**

I'm an eleventh grade high school computer science student in Canada. I'm doing pretty well in the course currently, I have a 96 in the course currently. We're working on our culminating 2D game these final 2 months in our semester. I'm using Object-Oriented Python and Pygame to develop my game.

The game I'm creating is a top down 2D zombie shooter. Very simple, kind of like a 2D versions of the Dead ops arcade game mode in the original Call Of Duty: Black ops.

I currently have a player, he moves around, rotates the mouse and shoot's bullet's in the direction of the mouse (Using a vector class I got online). I also use strings to design my levels, the level loader loads the strings and creates an array of blocks.

I have an array of zombie's that spawn and uses basic (non-vector) (logical) path-finding to get to the player. (Example: If the player is to the right of the zombie, zombie goes right).

Also an array of blocks. Now my collision works for the player. I use basic AABB Collision with the player to all the blocks and act if a collision is detected.

My blocks are in pygame.Rects and my zombie's and player both have collision rectangles that are half the size of their actual rectangles.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to keep my zombie's pathfinding it's way to the player, but have the zombies not go right through my blocks. So a basic collision detection algorithm, that goes after my pathfinding. Preventing the zombie's from being away from the blocks.

**What I've tried**

I tried applying the concept's explained online, I've also tried applying the same collision strategy that I've used with my player. I've tried double for loops ( for each block and each zombie ) that does an AABB check for each zombie wall but it just make's them kind of glitch through the wall.

**What I'm asking for**

I'm gonna put some code under. If anyone can give me diagrammed explanations or some code to how I would do this.  I'll try and give as much relevant code as I can in the bottom to provide a fundamental understanding of my thinking processes in terms of my code development. Also tips given for the code under would be nice as well.

**Relevant code**

Player Collision Code (level class, player instance passed in):

```
""" CHECK PLAYER COLLISION WITH WALLS """
    for i in range(1, 5): # run a for loop for all player walls
            player.setCollisionBound(i, False) # default all wall collisions to be false
    for block in range(len(self.Rects)): # run a for loop for all existing blocks
        for wall in range(1, 5): # run a for loop for all walls
            if player.getWall(wall).colliderect(self.Rects[block]): # Check if the current wall collided with the current block
                player.setCollisionBound(wall, True)
```

Zombie path-finding code (Zombie class):

```
        self.setD(0, 0) # Start Displacement at 0
        if self.Rect.colliderect(playerRect) != True: # See if the zombie is not overlapping the player
            if self.topWallCollided == False and self.bottomWallCollided == False and self.leftWallCollided == False and self.rightWallCollided == False: # check if theres no collisions
                if self.x > playerRect.center[0] + 2: # see if zombie is to the right of player, add 2 to end stutter area
                    self.setDX(-self.getVelocity())
                if self.x < playerRect.center[0] - 2: # see if zombie is to the left of player, subtract 2 to end stutter area
                    self.setDX(self.getVelocity())
                if self.y > playerRect.center[1] + 2: # see if player is on top of zombie, add 2 to end stutter area
                    self.setDY(-self.getVelocity())
                if self.y < playerRect.center[1] - 2: # see if player is under zombie , subtract 2 to end stutter area
                    self.setDY(self.getVelocity())
```

Zombie Collision Detection Code (level class, zombie manager passed in):

```
for zombie in range(len(self.zombieManager.getZombies())): # run a for loop for all zombies
                if self.zombieManager.getZombies()[zombie].getLifeStatus() == True: # check if the zombie is alive before you do anything with it
                    for block in range(len(self.Rects)): # run a for loop for all blocks
                        for wall in range(1, 5): # run a for loop for all walls
                            if self.zombieManager.getZombies()[zombie].getBlockCollisionWall(wall).colliderect(self.Rects[block]) == True: # check if the current zombie's current wall collided with the current block
                                self.zombieManager.getZombies()[zombie].setCollisionBound(wall, True) # set the current zombie's current wall's collision to be true
```

Zombie Collision Action Code (zombie class) :

```
if self.leftWallCollided == True:
            self.setD(self.getVelocity(), 0)
        if self.rightWallCollided == True:
            self.setD(-self.getVelocity(), 0)
        if self.topWallCollided == True:
            self.setD(0, self.getVelocity())
        if self.bottomWallCollided == True:
            self.setD(0, -self.getVelocity())
```

Zombie - Zombie Collision code (zombie manager class, works, so they don't overlap each other):

```
for zombie in range(self.zombies_am): # Update for all Zombies
            if self.zombies[zombie].getLifeStatus() == True: # Check if the Zombie is currently Alive before you do any relevant Data with it
                self.zombies[zombie].update(playerRect) # Update Zombie Data, give relevant data
                for i in range(self.zombies_am): # Check rect of all zombies
                    if self.zombies[i].getLifeStatus() == True: # Check if the Zombie is currently Alive before you do any relevant Data with it
                        if self.zombies[zombie].getWall(1).colliderect(self.zombies[i].getRect()) == True: # If the left wall of the first-current zombie (zombie) collides with any of the other zombies (i)
                            self.zombies[zombie].translate(self.zombies[zombie].getVelocity(), 0) # Translate the zombie to the right by it's own velocity
                        if self.zombies[zombie].getWall(2).colliderect(self.zombies[i].getRect()) == True: # If the right wall of the first-current zombie (zombie) collides with any of the other zombies (i)
                            self.zombies[zombie].translate(-self.zombies[zombie].getVelocity(), 0) # Translate the zombie to the left by it's own velocity
                        if self.zombies[zombie].getWall(3).colliderect(self.zombies[i].getRect()) == True: # If the top wall of the first-current zombie (zombie) collides with any of the other zombies (i)
                            self.zombies[zombie].translate(0, self.zombies[zombie].getVelocity()) # Translate the zombie to the bottom by it's own velocity
                        if self.zombies[zombie].getWall(4).colliderect(self.zombies[i].getRect()) == True: # If the bottom wall of the first-current zombie (zombie) collies with any of the other zombies (i)
                            self.zombies[zombie].translate(0, -self.zombies[zombie].getVelocity()) # Translate the zombie to the top by it's own velocity
```